# Specflow stepdefinitionreport for a solution

Tags: reporting, specflow

Hello i was wondering if there is a way to get the stepdefinitionreport for not only a project but for all projects of a solution. Something like:

```
specflow.exe stepdefitionreport .\path\to\solution.sln
```

The background is that I have a lot of different projects which use some common steps defined in a commons library.

I would like an overview through out the different projects to determine if a step should be consolidated and moved into the commons library.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option to create a solution wide stepdefinition report. But PRs are welcomed ;-)

If you can live with multiple reports, I would create a batch file for every project you have.